# load php file using form, submit button in html

Tags: php, html

The following codes are HTML and php code. I want if submit button is pressed than execute practice.php file(make test.txt file). But if I pressed the button php doesn't make file. Anyone know about this??

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY onLoad="tid=setInterval('refresh()',1000);">
        <div id="outputDiv"></div>
        <form method=post action="practice.php">
            <script language="JavaScript">
            function refresh()
            {           
                var HTML = "";
                HTML += "<input type=submit value=makefile>";
                document.getElementById("outputDiv").innerHTML = HTML;
            }
            </script>
        </form>
    </BODY>
</HTML> 


<html>
    <head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8">
    </head>

    <body>
                <?
                    $fp = fopen("test.txt", "w") or die("cannot open file");
                    $data = "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!";
                    fwrite($fp, $data);
                    fclose($fp);
                    echo "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!";
                ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You do know that the function `setInterval()` is used to make a function call at intervals repeatedly forever. In your case this means that the submit button is recreated every second forever. Use `setTimeout()` to make a delayed function call once.

Answer (score -1):

Use "a" flag, If file is not there it will automatically be created.

```
$fp = fopen("test.txt", "a")
```

Use JQuery, It would be simple.

```
<input type="submit" value="Load file" id="button"/>
<script>
//If document is ready.
$(document).ready(function(){

  //If button is clicked.
  $("#button").click(function(){

   //Load a file in "outputdiv" div.
   $("#outputDiv").load("test.txt");

   //Assuming you are trying to refresh div after 1000 ms sec, Therefor:
   setInterval(function(){

    $("#outputDiv").load("test.txt");

     },1000);
   });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: The "a" flag does not mean that the file will be created automatically. It means that the data will be appended at the end of the file instead of overwriting old data. The "w" flag will also try to create the file if it does not exist.

Comment: Are you sure? Read this: http://pk1.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php
"w" flag will place the file pointer at the beginning of the file and truncate the file to zero length, Hence "a" will add at the end.

Comment: That's exactly what I said in my previous comment?

Comment: Using both the "a" and "w" flags respectively will cause the call to try to create the file if it does not previously exist. The difference is that "a" will cause any subsequent writes will be appended to end instead of overwriting previous data. Appending data is irrelevant as the OP never states that he wishes to do so.

Comment: fwrite($fp, $data); there is a fwrite function, He is trying to write the file.

Comment: Saving a one line comment in a text file and re-write the whole file again with another one line comment is good? Isn't that irrelevant?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20832/discussion-between-waleed-and-snipes83)

Answer (score -1):

You must put the submit button inside the form element. The script puts the submit button inside the `<div id="outputDiv"></div>` element which is outside of the form element. When you press submit the browser does not know which form to submit.

For example this would work better:

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY onLoad="tid=setInterval('refresh()',1000);">
        <form method=post action="practice.php" id="form">
            <script language="JavaScript">
            function refresh()
            {           
                var HTML = "";
                HTML += "<input type=submit value=makefile>";
                document.getElementById("form").innerHTML += HTML;
            }
            </script>
        </form>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Please don't mind but why put it in form element when he is using JavaScript?

Comment: @Waleed He's using javascript to insert the submit button, not to submit the form. To submit the user needs to press the button which does not not reside in any form element.

Comment: Thank you @snipes83. But, if I press the button, not make file but show download window. So if I download file and open it, it is my php source code.I think it is not execute source code. Are you know about this?

Comment: @Jimmy That's probably because you're running the web page on a server that doesn't support PHP. You need to upload both the html and PHP files to a PHP enabled web server. Alternatively get PHP up and running on you own machine.

Comment: @snipes83 If he would run file on a server which doesn't support php, It would just show all the php code in the web browser window instead of showing to download it.

Comment: Ehm....Make a new php with a function, Run it on webbrowser without using any server, It would show you the whole code instead of asking to download it.